# How to silently prevent Webform spam (specific names, email addresses)?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am using Webform on Drupal 8; I have a few spambots that fill out the exact same form in the same way every day.

I want to do some kind of validation that automatically blocks these postings.  For example, if the name given is "Spambot 1", I want to discard the webform submission automatically.

Drupal 7 has the **Webform Validation** module but this has [not yet been ported to Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation/issues/2220971).

I found a code snippet on [adding custom validation to a webform element](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element), but this seems to be for providing helpful errors to allow the user to re-submit the webform, whereas I want to make it seem like the form was submitted but silently discard the submission.

Comment: Is Honeypot out for D8?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I have Honeypot enabled but I'm still getting a few specific spambots every day.

Comment: Even if you implement that, you still risk in the future getting spammed by new bots that fill out the form differently. If you use [reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) that will be the end of it.

Comment: Definitly reCaptcha as @NoSssweat suggested, there even is an "invisbile" reCaptcha that is completely hidden from real users most of the time. It is silent to normal users and prevents submissions / forces captcha only on suspicious submits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the available SPAM protection modules for Drupal 8 are listed on the [Webform Add-ons documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-add-ons#spam).

Text inputs now support patterns, you could explore creating a [negative lookahead pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex) like ^(?!.*spam).*$,

Answer (score 1):

To Avoid spam keywords on Webforms with field. just check this out, https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_spam_words

Administrators can provide the ability to add spam keywords, Error message, Webform field name.